# Test Framework Quit Unexpectedly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I keep getting the following exception when I run scalatest via Intellij. same error happens when I run it in command line through gradle. so far I tried the following with no avail:

- Cleared gradle cache
- Re - imported the project
- Bumped scalatest
  version. current version - ('org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:2.2.4')
- Reinstalled scala plugin

I was wondering if anyone encountered similar error or have any idea what might be wrong?

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.scalatest.time.Days$.<init>(Units.scala:291)
    at org.scalatest.time.Days$.<clinit>(Units.scala)
    at org.scalatest.time.Span$.<init>(Span.scala:585)
    at org.scalatest.time.Span$.<clinit>(Span.scala)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.<init>(Runner.scala:779)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.<clinit>(Runner.scala)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at     org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

Full list of dependencies:

```
compile('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6') { transitive = true }
compile('org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:2.2.4') { transitive = true }
compile 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.3'
compile 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'
compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
compile 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.1.0'
compile 'net.liftweb:lift-json_2.12:3.3.0'
```

Comment: @MarioGalic updated with all dependencies thx.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. it is caused by following package.
Using different version fixed it.

> compile 'net.liftweb:lift-json_2.12:3.3.0'